# Bitstream PageFlex Storefront Server Crash

Tags: windows, server, registry, licensing

this question is about PageFlex StoreFront server crash and recovery. We were able to recover the OS Drive and all Storage. We moved it via clonning to a new box.

The License Administrator displays the Host Server and License as OK -- no errors. The software runs as it always has except we have this error in event viewer regarding the PFLicenseServer Service:

PFLicenseServer
Computer: WEBSERVER
Description: Licensing failure: Not enough licenses for Pageflex Server Job machine 'WEBSERVER'.

And yet the License Administrator displays OK!
On reboot a Service startup problem alert popsup. Any ideas how I can resolve this? I've scoured the registry and the path to the Service is correct. So I'm at a brick wall.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can check:

Server Admin
 - Is the host that failed still in the list of hosts?
 - Does the failed host still have engines it can run? Try setting Minimum Idle Engines and Maximum Concurrent Jobs to 0.
 - Host logs

Licensing Administrator:

- How many CPUs are in use?

More information on what version of Pageflex you are running would be helpful. Also is this a server license or are you running storefront? If Storefront, does this come up successfully?